# Managing OS processes not started by Erlang code

Tags: linux, macos, process, operating-system, erlang

Erlang supplies two ways for managing OS processes the simple `os` module and the better API built around `erlang:open_port()`. I've also found an interesting project on GitHub partially written in C++ called [erlexec](https://github.com/saleyn/erlexec).

Anyway all of this doesn't fit the need of controlling a running process. I'd like to:

- Get OS PID from process name.
- Send signals to the process.
- (Optional: Send data to the process).
- Check process statistics: at least **CPU Usage %** and **Used Memory** (same data of commands like `top`).
- Being able to support at least Linux and Mac OS X platforms.

After doing some research I've concluded that, in Linux platform for example, I need to use a mix of C calls and reading from `/proc` filesystem.

Am I on the right path or there's another way (*excluding calling shell commands to get data or perform operations*)?

Is there out a library I wasn't able to find (an Erlang one or a C library well suited to be called from Erlang?

Comment: IMO you're best off going with erlexec. If it doesn't do something you need, it'd be much easier to fork it and add what you need (and then contribute it back) than starting from scratch.

Comment: Fork erlexec could be a good idea. The problem with it and Erlang open_port(), as I said, is that you lack control of running processes. You need to start your own to control it.